# Route traffic through Debian server

Tags: routing

I am developing software where I have a Listener and multiple Clients which connect to this listener. During development I hard code the Listener IP address which all Clients connect to, however this will not be possible for the final version. The listener needs to be portable, meaning that it will be listening from different networks at different times, which will not be port forwarded. All communication is TCP, going both ways.

To solve this I intend to use a static server that will act as a middleman for the listener and clients, meaning that clients will connect to this port forwarded server which will route the traffic to the listener. The listener will then also connect to the middleman and the clients and listener can engage in regular TCP comms. Is there a not extremely time consuming way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "extremely time consuming," but you will need some "middleman" device to act as a meeting point. That device can either forward traffic between the clients, or let the devices know each others' addresses.

Comment: I do have a middleman device. I intend to use my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all on the same LAN, it sounds like you should be using multicast. You can have the server subscribe to a particular multicast group (you can register an Ad Hoc group with IANA, or you could use a group in the Organization-Local scope). The clients could find the server by sending a message to the multicast group to exchange IP addresses with the server, which could then be used to create the TCP connections. In that way, you would seem to not need the middleman device.

Comment: It is not on the same LAN sadly.

Comment: Please explain where the devices are located in relation to each other.

Comment: There is a Listener that may be on any network in the world, networks which I do not own. There are clients that are also on various networks I do not own. There is a middleman server on my private network.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks you do not directly control are off-topic here. By the way, this is the type of thing that many business networks will block because of the Target intrusion and the IoT exploit. It opens a back door into a network. The company I work for completely blocks such things on the production network, requiring an isolated network for this type of connection. You may run into that at many companies.

Comment: My bad, I was not aware. Do you know of a stackexchange community that is fitting for my question?

Comment: It may be better on [sf] from the network perspective on a business network ([su] for personal networks). The programming and application design can be asked on [so].